# How to verify that two different .csv files column ids match with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have two different `.csv` files, but they have the same `id` colummn.

```
file_1.csv:
id, column1, column2
4543DFGD_werwe_23, string
4546476FGH34_wee_24, string
....
45sd234_w32rwe_2342342, string
```

The other one:

```
file_1.csv:
id, column3, column4
4543DFGD_werwe_23, bla bla bla
4546476FGH34_wee_24, bla bla bla
....
45sd234_w32rwe_2342342, bla bla bla
```

How can I verify that this two columns match(have the same id) or are the same with the csv module or with pandas?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By csv module:

1. Open file both files.
2. Reader file by `csv reader()` method.
3. Create dictionary as first item from the row is key and  value is row.
4. Use `set` `intersection` method to get same keys from the dictionaries.
5. Print result.

code:

```
import csv

file1 =  '/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/fil1.csv'
file2 =  '/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/fil2.csv'

with open(file1) as fp1:
    root = csv.reader(fp1)
    rows1 = {}
    for i in root:
        rows1[i[0]]=i
    if "id" in rows1:
        del rows1["id"]

with open(file2) as fp1:
    root = csv.reader(fp1)
    rows2 = {}
    for i in root:
        rows2[i[0]]=i
    if "id" in rows2:
        del rows2["id"]

result = set(rows1.keys()).intersection(set(rows2.keys()))

print "Same Id :", list(result)
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 27.py
Same Id : ['4546476FGH34_wee_24', '4543DFGD_werwe_23', '45sd234_w32rwe_2342342']
```

Comment: Welcome. I am also looking above pandas implementation

Comment: Thanks for the help but I got this:`Same Id : []` maybe I am doing something wrong, how can I fix it?.

Comment: pass me ur py file with input files on email-  vivekbsable@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

After loading you can call [`equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.equals.html#pandas.Series.equals) on the id column:

```
df['id'].equals(df1['id'])
```

This will return `True` of `False` if they are exactly the same, in length and same values in the same order

```
In [3]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(10)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(10)})
df.id.equals(df1.id)
Out[3]:
True

In [7]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.arange(10)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0,1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
df.id.equals(df1.id)
Out[7]:
False
In [8]:

df.id == df1.id
Out[8]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

To load the csvs:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('file_2.csv') # I'm assuming your real other csv is not the same name as file_1.csv
```

Then you can perform the same comparison as above:

```
df.id.equals(df1.id)
```

If you just want to compare the id columns you can specify just to load that column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv', usecols=['id'])
df1 = pd.read_csv('file_2.csv', usecols=['id'])
```

Comment: Wow.. nice. Thanks for the help. How can I change the `'id':np.arange(10)` for the lenght of a large file?.

Comment: You're a little confused, my code shows sample data, I will update to show how to load the csv in pandas and perform the same comparison

Comment: I can tell you that the pandas csv module is lightning fast at loading csv files, faster than the python standard csv module, see the link: http://wesmckinney.com/blog/a-new-high-performance-memory-efficient-file-parser-engine-for-pandas/

Comment: Thanks, I tried this aproach but it seems that is comparing the number of the line instead of the ìd, here is what I [tried](http://dpaste.com/15P9Z65) @EdChum

Comment: @ml_guy No, ignore the `np.arange` portion, straight after loading the csv's just do `df.id.equals(df1.id)` no need to construct new dfs

Comment: Also tried this:`df = pd.read_csv('path/file2.csv', usecols=['id'])
df1 = pd.read_csv('path/file1.csv', usecols=['id'])
print df.id == df1.id
` and I got this exception:`  print df.id == df1.id
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 551, in wrapper
    raise ValueError('Series lengths must match to compare')
ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare`. Both files have the same lenght

Comment: then you have something wrong with your csvs, try without the `usecols` param so just `df = pd,read_csv('path/file1.csv')`

Comment: Ok, Now I tried this: `print df.id.equals(df1.id)` and I got `False`. How can I visualize the whole dataframe in order to see what happened?. Thank you very much for helping me! @EdChum

Comment: Any idea of how to print the whole dataframe?... that's why I used that function. Thanks

Comment: `pd.set_option('display.max_rows=-1')`

Comment: Huh... thanks for your help, but again I got this:`pd.set_option('display.max_rows=-1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/config.py", line 217, in __call__
    return self.__func__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/config.py", line 107, in _set_option
    raise ValueError("Must provide an even number of non-keyword "
ValueError: Must provide an even number of non-keyword arguments` @EdChum

Comment: sorry typo mistake should be `pd.set_option('display.max_rows',1)`

Comment: Like this: `pd.set_option('display.max_rows'=1)` or `pd.set_option('display.max_rows'=-1)` ?  I got `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression `thanks! @EdChum

Comment: I solved with this: `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 3000)`